# I am running a web app and want to update my SQL Server user profile database with C# code but no matter what I do I cannot get it to work

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I am trying to create a MyAccount page for a website I am making using ASP.NET and Bootstrap with html and C# running in the background for our objects. We are using SQL Server to run our databases and I am having a LOT of troubles getting my updates to go through. I am using a test user profile I had my partner hard insert into the system as I have not programmed the account creation system yet, only the login.

The issue is that when I run my update code the SQL Server database does not update with the passed information. I receive no exceptions and I know my connection string works as I use it to log in and drag contents of my database into text boxes on the main screen. Because of this I have no idea why it is not updating and I feel very lost.

I have removed bits of the connection string itself as this server is not my own and I don't want my professor's personal connection and login credentials being on the internet.

My debug label running a query tells me each time I attempt to change the state variable on the item that 1 row was effected.

The user profile I am trying to update has the following information stored in it.

```
Username: MarshallE  
Email: Test1234  
Password: Test1234!  
First Name: Marshall  
Last Name: Emmer  
Properties Rented: Prime Place  
Universities Attended Oklahoma State University  
State: N/A (My partner just added this and didn't update the profile)
```

Here is my code I used to try and update the thing:

```
protected void btnRegAcctUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // This unit's job is to update the database of the specified user with the info in the text boxes
    // Make sure the password fields are the same
    if (txtAcctPass1.Text == txtAcctPass2.Text)
    {
        lblAcctDebug.Text = "";

        SqlConnection MyConnection = new SqlConnection();
        MyConnection.ConnectionString = "Server= (N/A ;Database=F19_groupRoss;User Id=groupRoss;Password = (N/A);";

        string MyUpdateStatement;
        MyUpdateStatement = "UPDATE dbo.UserID SET Email = @Email, Password = @Password, FirstName = @FirstName, LastName = @LastName, Universities = @University, Town = @Town, State = @State" + " WHERE UserID = @UserID";

        SqlCommand MySqlCmd = new SqlCommand(MyUpdateStatement, MyConnection);

        // These are the values we will be overriding the database with
        MySqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserID", (string)Session["UserID"]);
        MySqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", txtAcctFirstName.Text);
        MySqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName", txtAcctLastName.Text);
        MySqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", txtAcctEmail.Text);
        MySqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", txtAcctPass1.Text);
        MySqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@State", txtAcctState.Text);
        MySqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Town", txtAcctTown.Text);
        MySqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@University", txtAcctUniversity.Text);

        // Open the connection
        MyConnection.Open();

        int rows = MySqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        lblDebug2.Text = "Rows affected: " + rows;

        MyConnection.Close();
    }
    else
    {
        lblAcctDebug.Text = "Error: Please ensure the text in the new password and password confirmation boxes are identical";
    }
}
```

If anyone can tell me what I am doing wrong I would REALLY appreciate it!

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201812/discussion-on-question-by-marshall-emmer-i-am-running-a-web-app-and-want-to-upda).

Comment: did you debug your code

Comment: Are you getting an exception at all with any of this?  Are you able to run a profiler on your DB to see what exactly is being executed?  Also - are you sure that the session user id is correct?

Comment: Add  MySqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text; and ensure userID is correct one and for testing try to hardcode the value and verify it.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding your parameters like this:

```
MysqlCmd.Parameters.Add(New Parameter(@FirstName, txtAcctFirstName.text));
```